# HTML Step attribute is not working properly

Tags: html, jquery

I'm using the step attribute in the HTML range element

I set the step attribute value to 1. It is supposed to show the range in series (1,2,3,4....) but for some unknown reason, it is showing the gap of 10 in every step (10,20,30,40...)

Here is my code

HTML

```
<input value="1" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="10" name="rangeone" id="rangeone">  
<span id="result"></span>0</h5>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rangeone").on('input', function() {
         var result = $('#rangeone').val();
         $('#result').text(result); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code must be incomplete, check out this jsfiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/t03meobp/` it works as supposed to.

Comment: The issue is that there is a zero outside the `span` that never changes - so any number has a zero added. Also - the stray `</h5>` tag needs to be removed

Comment: Oops! Didn't notice it! Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

remove the 0 from the span, `<span id="result"></span></h5>` the zero is getting added to the result

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rangeone").on('input', function() {
         var result = $('#rangeone').val();
         $('#result').text(result); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" step="1" min="0" max="10" name="rangeone" id="rangeone">  
<span id="result"></span></h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `>0</h5>` from the end of span tag

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rangeone").on('input', function() {
         var result = $('#rangeone').val();
         $('#result').text(result); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input value="1" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="10" name="rangeone" id="rangeone">  
<span id="result"></span>
```